# UICollectionViewController not validly loading from NIB

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

iOS 6.0, testing on an iPhone 5

I am loading a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` from a nib.
When I hot the `awakeFromNib` method, it claims that the view is loaded.
Calling `collectionView` returns `nil`.

I'm therefore having a problem registering the nib which to load my cells from.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  if ([self isViewLoaded])
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] registered with %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
          self.collectionView);

  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCollectionCell" bundle:nil];
  [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:NIB_ID];
}
```

Output from above:

```
2012-09-22 19:21:49.129 myApp[7182:907] [MyCollectionViewController awakeFromNib] registered with (null)
```

Also, `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` are not called (expected when loading from a nib).

I fail with exception when trying to load the cells.

Current workaround, redundantly registering nib in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCollectionCell" bundle:nil];
  [collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:NIB_ID];
```

**Questions:** Have you run across this?  Do you see the error of my ways?  Is this a known bug?

---

**Edit**: additional information …

breaking in awakeFromNib, `collectionView` appears inaccessible

```
(lldb) po [self view]
(UIView *) $1 = 0x1f158400 <UICollectionView: 0x1f158400; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1ed8fcf0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ed8f790>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1ed919a0>
(lldb) po [self collectionView]
(UICollectionView *) $2 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

modifying the `wakeFromNib` to use `view` instead of `collectionView` is a better workaround:

```
  [(UICollectionView *)self.view registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:NIB_ID];
```

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I ended up solving the issue registering both the xib and class in viewDidLoad. Are you registering the class as well as the nib?  I had to register both?  `[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"rPhotoCell"];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyPhotoCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"rPhotoCell"];`

Comment: @bshirley I have used the (UICollectionView *)self.view trick. Thank you.

Comment: You did not call super awakeFromNib. Also you should be doing your configuration of the controller in view did load. If view did load is not being called then you need to take a look at the reason for that.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I've slept since then, and don't recall the project it was in.  I think I may have delayed this code until the `viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 3):

Loading a view controller from a nib is not intended to load the view. The iOS lazy-loading scheme will only load the view once something attempts to access it.  This is intended to limit memory consumption for the things which have not been put on the screen.

When you use 'self.view', the UIViewController base class accessor for the 'view' property will load the view if it has not been loaded. (Then your viewDidLoad will be called.)

If you provide a viewDidLoad method for your viewController, you could register your UINib there.